# How to force component to reender in react-native, when click in child component button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a cart component containing 3 products components, when i delete product from the cart by clicking on delete button i wanna the cart component to give like a live preview of the delete, showing me only the products remains

Comment: Send callback to child component from parent with a prop, call it when clicked, remove item from parent state in callback.

Comment: Can you add the code to support that?

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways, you need to use a state management implementation.
You could try redux or mobx. There are other alternatives too. Mobx could get you started quickly if the application is not complex .

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possibilities to solve this.

1. Redux(or you can use other library). This will automatically update the component if the props changes
2. If you are not using libraries like redux to manage store of your
   application then you can play by passing a method from your component to your cart and calling this method in your cart when necessary action is been done. Inside this method just toggle a boolean variable of your state or you can do anything you wish to like passing the data as param from the cart and utilising that value in your component; this may refresh your component.